# Install4j - How to get version of Installer?

Tags: java, javafx, install4j

I´d like to get the version of the current instalation, I tried:

```
String myVersion = (String)context.getVariable("sys.version");
```

However I dont know how to get `context`.

Comment: See http://server5.javadent.de:800/maven2/install4j/install4j/4.2.4/install4j_win32/doc/api/javadoc/com/install4j/api/events/InstallerEvent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your own code (not in the installer), call

```
com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables.getCompilerVariable("sys.version")
```

In the installer (when you have a context), it would be

```
context.getCompilerVariable("sys.version")
```